# curl --resolve equivalent in PHP CURL library

Tags: php, http, ssl, curl

Is there an equivalent for `curl --resolve ....` in PHP CURL library ?

Background: I have round-robin DNS (one domain name resolves to multiple IPs), and I want to send a request to a *specific* host. I use apache name-based virtual hosts, and thus a correct domain name must appear in the HTTP request.

I have tried specifying the IP in the request URL: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '127.0.0.1')`, and using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Host: example.com')`. It works for HTTP, but for HTTPS I get SSL verification error (apparently CURL verifies certificate vs. URL hostname and NOT `Host:` hostname).

Using `hosts` file is not a convenient option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, the best way to get an answer to how *any* curl option translates to libcurl (or PHP/CURL) is by using the [--libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--libcurl) option.

If you do, you will learn that [--resolve](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--resolve) translates to [CURLOPT_RESOLVE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html) with libcurl, supported in PHP [since 5.5.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0). Supported by libcurl since [7.21.3](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_21_3).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately PHP/CURL doesn't support CURLOPT_RESOLVE yet (it's in the trunk but not yet incorporated into stable release).

Comment: `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` is now supported by PHP/CURL. This was added in PHP 5.5.0 ([Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.0))

Comment: Note that you must have a version of lib curl installed that supports it. Even if you have PHP 5.5.38 like I do, if your underlying version of libcurl is <7.21.3 it will not work!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to this with the help of Python.

In the .php file, just echo the output of python:

```
<?php
echo passthru("python python.py");
?>
```

In python.py:

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('127.0.0.1');
url = "example.com"
conn.request("GET", url)
content = conn.getresponse()
print content.read()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to bother to fork another process, just fork curl itself with the "--resolve" option versus yet another script.