# Call Laravel app's functions from CakePHP, securely

Tags: php, api, cakephp, laravel, nginx

**Scenario**

I have a CakePHP project  (project.com) which currently serves as the duo-purpose (app & webserver) of my website.

But, I am moving the business layer to a new Laravel project which might reside on the same server. It exposes an api to be used by CakePHP project to make calls. This also works as my public api server and exposes all the (internal+public) methods via `https://api.project.com/internal/v1` & `https://api.project.com/v1` endpoints respectively.

**Problem**

Currently I am making the calls from cakePHP to Laravel modules over the network, like regular user, using the REST api at `https://api.project.com/internal/v1/` using token auth. 
But this introduces security holes and also introduces latency. And since both applications will reside in a single server (or at least, servers with-in private network), how can I make the calls private and not have then travel over the public network.

**FYI** :
nGinx (`+php-fpm`) serves both the apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set access limitations in Nginx for certain IPs. Ideally only `ALLOW 127.0.0.1;` and any other IPs to access those urls .`DENY all;` to block everyone else.

```
location internal/ {
    DENY ALL;
    ALLOW 127.0.0.1;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html

Accessing the private network addresses can either by accessing it by the IP or changing the `/etc/hosts` file to point the domain to the private network address.

`api.project.com 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Is there a way to force cURL to resolve api.project.com to 127.0.0.1 rather than putting it into hosts ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with just curl, but maybe a HTTP proxy?

Comment: I just stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433016/curl-resolve-equivalent-in-php-curl-library and the question mentions the answer. I don't need HTTPS tho, cz its internal request.